# TypeError: this.props.onSelectChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to bind a state from Parent **App.jsx**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      select: '', 
    };
    this.onSelectChange = this.onSelectChange.bind(this);
  };
```

via a callback function, like so:

```
onSelectChange(newSelect){ 
    this.setState({ select: newSelect });
  }
```

and pass it as props in `render()`:

```
<Route exact path='/seeds' render={() => (
  <Seeds
    onSelectChange={this.onSelectChange}
  />
)} />
```

Then, at Child **Seeds.jsx**, I have:

```
class Seeds extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    formSeeds: {
      my_bean:''
    }
  }
    this.handleSubmitMyBean = this.handleSubmitMyBean.bind(this);
    this.handleMyBeanFormChange = this.handleMyBeanFormChange.bind(this);
};
```

`handleSubmit()` (with callback function being triggered) and `handleChange()` events:

```
  handleMyBeanFormChange(event) {
     console.log(event)
     const obj = Object.assign({}, this.state.formSeeds);
     obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
     this.setState({ formSeeds: obj });
  };

  handleSubmitMyBean(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {userId} = this.props
    var headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
        }
    const data = {
      my_bean: this.state.formSeeds.my_bean
    };

    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/handle_seeds/${userId}`;
    axios.post(url, data, headers)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ redirect:true} );
        this.props.onSelectChange(this.state.formSeeds.my_bean); // <----------------
      })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error); 
    });
  };
```

and a form in `render()`, like so:

```
<form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmitMyBean(event) }>
    <div className="field">
     <input
      name="my_bean"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter Bean"
      value={this.state.formSeeds.my_bean}
      onChange={this.handleMyBeanFormChange}
    </div>
```

but at submit I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: this.props.onSelectChange is not a function
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Super wierd, could you build it in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/fork/react  :) after you build it send the link and comment here and i will take care of it [with some dummy data]

Comment: handleSubmitSeeds where is this function ??? ...

Comment: sorry, it was mixed. edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes in you `handleMyBeanFormChange` function regarding event and it's working fine now. Please try the codesandbox code.

And I noticed that `this.handleSubmitSeeds` function is missing in your code.

> https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-moon-5ip35

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: hi, the link is dead...404

Comment: And use this url in sandbox url bar. https://5ip35.csb.app/seeds

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid binding each function by using arrow functions like so:

```
function = ( ) => {

}
```

Also you can try console logging props in your child component to see if there are any references to your function in the props.